# iPhone- Error With Spritekit Game

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, unrecognized-selector

I'm making a app using Apple's Spritekit framework. My app has multiple view controllers and everything works fine. However, I tried to make a scene that I would load in one of my viewcontrollers, but that did not work. I get no errors at all: it just does not work. Everything works except when I try to load my scene, everything crashes. Also, I was thinking, could my problem be that I have already added a view and put labels and buttons, etc... on that view before I load my scene? To elaborate, could the problem be that I have already added uiimages, etc... to the view using interface builder before I loaded my scene programmatically? Any help would be great. Here is my code for the view controller where I call my scene:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;



    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];



    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

And here is my code for the actual scene:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    /* Setup your scene here */



        SKSpriteNode *mainTurrentSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"mainTurrent.png"];

        mainTurrentSprite.position = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, 0);

        [self addChild:mainTurrentSprite];



        }
    return self;
}
```

And here is my crash/error log :

```
2014-07-22 14:32:34.783 Doodle Defense[6713:60b] -[UIView presentScene:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9a32630
2014-07-22 14:32:34.786 Doodle Defense[6713:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView presentScene:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9a32630'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x019231e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0168e8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x019c0243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0191350b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x019130ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   Doodle Defense                      0x000020b1 -[GameViewController viewDidLoad] + 337
    6   UIKit                               0x0034b33d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
    7   UIKit                               0x0034b5d9 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    8   UIKit                               0x0035af89 -[UIViewController shouldAutorotate] + 36
    9   UIKit                               0x0035b2d1 -[UIViewController _preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentationInWindow:fromInterfaceOrientation:] + 297
    10  UIKit                               0x005f93d5 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:] + 2330
    11  UIKit                               0x003575d5 -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 6538
    12  UIKit                               0x00357aef -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 130
    13  UIKit                               0x00357b2f -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:] + 56
    14  UIKit                               0x007a1e00 -[UIStoryboardModalSegue perform] + 271
    15  UIKit                               0x00790f0c -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 174
    16  UIKit                               0x00790f87 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 115
    17  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x016a0880 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    18  UIKit                               0x0022e3b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    19  UIKit                               0x0022e345 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    20  UIKit                               0x0032fbd1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    21  UIKit                               0x0032ffc6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    22  UIKit                               0x0032f243 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    23  UIKit                               0x0026dddd -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    24  UIKit                               0x0026e9d1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1117
    25  UIKit                               0x002405f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    26  UIKit                               0x0022a353 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x018ac77f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x018ac10b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x018c91ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x018c89d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x018c87eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    32  GraphicsServices                    0x039035ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    33  GraphicsServices                    0x0390342b GSEventRun + 104
    34  UIKit                               0x0022cf9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    35  Doodle Defense                      0x00002add main + 141
    36  libdyld.dylib                       0x01f56701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Your view controller's view is not a SKView. Also launching from viewDidLoad is not recommended due to incorrect frame size for landscape games. For both there is plenty of Q&A here.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D so how would I fix my problem? I changed the viewDidLoad to viewWillLayoutSubview but how do I fix the viewcontroller/SKView issue.

Comment: depends, definitely check the view assigned in Interfacebuilder/storyboards editor